# Classes and dependency injections in Angular 1.x and EcmaScript 2015

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have use babel, gulp and browserify for build my app.

I have simple controller, like this:

```
export default class MyCtrl() {
    constructor() {
    }

    someMethod() {
        // I know that this is not pure code, but it is not part of current question
        return $http.post('/api/some/url/', {some: 'data'});
    }
}
```

The problem is with dependency injection (DI). This is simple to use 'ng-annotate' in constructor:

```
// @ngInject
constructor($http) {
    // $http is resolved here
}
```

but not working in other methods:

```
// @ngInject
someMethod($http) {
    // FAIL. $http is resolved, because angular DI working only on main ctrl function
}
```

I have found 4 different approach to solve this prolem:

```
// 1, using this
constructor($http) {
    this.http = $http;
}
someMethod() {
    this.http.get(...);
}

// 2, using WeekMap
var deps = new WeekMap()
class MyCtrl {
    constructor($http) {
        deps.set(this, {http: $http)
    }
    someMethod() {
        deps.get(this).http.get(...);
    }
}

// 3, using inherited class
class Injectable {
    constructor() {
        var injector = angular.element(document).injector();
        for (var prop in this) {
            let fn = this[prop];
            if(angular.isFunction(fn)) {
                this[prop] = function(...args) {
                    injector.invoke(fn, this, args);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class MyCtrl extends Injectable {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    someMethod($http) {
        $http.get(...)
    }
    // but then I can't use not injected values =(
    //someAnotherMethod(valueFromCtrl, $http) {
    //}
}

// 4, manually using injector

function di(...args) {
    var injector = angular.element(document).injector()
    if(args.length == 1) {
        return injector.get(args[0])
    }
    var ret = args.map( name => injector.get(name) )
    return args.length > 1 ? ret : ret[0];
}

class MyCtrl extends Injectable {
    constructor() {
    }
    someMethod($http) {
        var $http = di('$http');
        $http.get(...)
    }
}
```

1 and 2 methods need lot of code for each dependency.
3 method have a problem with values passed to method from controller
I think the best method is number 4, but not sure is there some other issues.

The question is which method is more powerfull?
Are there any best practices for using DI in ES clasess sub-methods ?

// UPD
Methods 1 and 2 need lot of extra code, e.g. for factories:

```
export default class SomeFactory {
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http
    }

    getItems() {
        this.$http.get('/').then(console.log.bind(console))
    }

    static makeFactory($http) {
        return new SomeFactory($http)
    }
}

angular.module('someModule', []).factory(SomeFactory.makeFactory)
```

Comment: use method 1. The other methods are unnecessarily complex. Also injecting directly into methods other than your constructor is not a good idea as they will also need to take parameters that are not injected.

Comment: Method 1 needs lot of extra code for each dependency (I have add example in question)

Comment: your factory example doesn't need a `makeFactory` function. it should just be `angular.module('someModule', []).service(SomeFactory)`